# R: Replace subplot created with facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data like this:

```
df <- tibble(
  key = c("v1", "v1", "v1", "v1", "v2", "v2", "v2", "v2", "v3"),
  values = c(1, 2, 4, 2, 5, 8, 3, 1, 0)
)
```

and create a histogram of each value:

```
plot <- df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = values)) +
    geom_histogram(aes(y = ..count..)) +
    facet_wrap(~key, scales = "free", nrow = 1)
```

[image]

These values represent occurences of a specific observation. What I want is to replace a plot with some default text like "No data", if the histogram shows only one bar at `x = 0`, like it is the case in the third subplot. Is there a way to achieve this?

EDIT:
Goal:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted, but you may try

**ver1**

```
df %>%
  group_by(key) %>%
  mutate(values = values * ifelse(n() == 1, NA, 1),
         text = ifelse(n() ==1, "No \n observation \n available", NA)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = values)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..count..)) +
  geom_label(aes(label = text, y = 0.5, x = 1)) +
  facet_wrap(~key, scales = "free", nrow = 1)
```

[image]

**ver2**

```
df %>%
  mutate(values = as.factor(values)) %>%
  group_by(key, values) %>%
  summarize(count = n()) %>%
  group_by(key) %>%
  mutate(count = count * ifelse(n() == 1, NA, 1),
         text = ifelse(n() ==1, "No \nobservation \n available", NA)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = values)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = count)) +
  geom_label(aes(label = text, y = 1)) +
  facet_wrap(~key, scales = "free", nrow = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: I updated my question with a "goal" plot

Comment: @mc1893 I add new code and plot.

Comment: that looks quite nice - thanks! I only have one problem now. As the data presented in my question is only a dummy, it differs from my real data. My real data has much more different possible values, e.g. up to 1000 different values. With your plot, for every single value a bar is plotted which does not look good. Is there a way to automatically determine the best number of bins, like geom_histogram does?

Comment: @mc1893 Just in my thought, if there do exist thousands of `values`, it's not a good idea to plot those with bar graph. In **ver2**, as you can see in first two plots(`v1` and `v2`), it automatically take care of width of bar. However, if you want **ver1** style, it can be done manually make width by how many unique `values` per `key`s (`v1` have three and `v2` have four) or by default and automatically, thin bars. You may categorize your values by some intervals of them, make number of total bars per facets. If it is able to describe what you want, maybe I can write a code for that.

Answer (score 0):

If "0" is not "NA", than I would plot it.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(
  key = c("v1", "v1", "v1", "v1", "v2", "v2", "v2", "v2", "v3"),
  values = c(1, 2, 4, 2, 5, 8, 3, 1, 0)
) %>%
  mutate(key = factor(key, levels = c("v1", "v2", "v3")))

plot <- df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = values, fill = key)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = ..count..)) +
  facet_wrap(~ key)

plot
```

[image]